# Filter element if checkboxes are check or not JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a problem with my code. I coded a search bar which filter checkboxes by their name and I coded a function which only display the checkboxes selected. But there is a conflict.

Everytime I click on "Selected" everything is passing to a display : none;

So I tried to wrap my search bar into some div but it's not working as I imagined. I know that .parent() is the problem because it impacts the parent of my search bar, but I need it to hide the elements not selected so I don't succeed in solving it.

Here is the snippet to understand what I mean. Update it in your answer to let me see what was wrong.

Hope you guys will be able to help me.

```js
function All() {
  $("input").parent().show();
}

function OnlySelecteds() {
  $("input:not(:checked)").parent().hide();
}


//array of options
var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = "January";
choices[1] = "February";
choices[2] = "March";
choices[3] = "April";
choices[4] = "May";
choices[5] = "June";
choices[6] = "July";
choices[7] = "August";
choices[8] = "September";
choices[9] = "October";
choices[10] = "November";
choices[11] = "December";

var target = new Array()
target[0] = "9";
target[1] = "8";
target[2] = "11";

var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in choices) {
  //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
  j = i.toString();

  val = j;
  //cap will be the value/text of choices[i]
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  cap = choices[i];
  var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cbh.appendChild(cb);
  cb.name = cap;
  cb.value = val;
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click', updateText)
  if (target.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
    cb.checked = true;
  }

}

updateText();

function updateText() {
  t.value = [null, ...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s, el) => el && el.checked ? s = (s || '') + el.value + '$#' : s || '')
}


function updateCheckboxes(x) {
  if ($('#SearchBar').val() == '') {
    $('#checkboxes > label').show();
  } else {
    $('#checkboxes > label').hide();
    $('#checkboxes > label:contains(' + $('#SearchBar').val() + ')').show();
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#data {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.multiselect {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1px;
  border: none;
  width: 100vw;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 75px;
}

.checkboxes {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="All()">All</span> | <span onclick="OnlySelecteds()">Selected</span> | <input id="SearchBar" placeholder="Search for options.." type="text" oninput="updateCheckboxes(this)" autocomplete="off">
<form>
  <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div id="c_b">
        <div id="checkboxes">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<textarea id="t" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than only hide all your unchecked input, I would prefer to show all input first. that way, even after I searched something, then if I click "selected", it would still show all the selected input

```
function OnlySelecteds() {
  $("input").parent().show();
  $("input:not(:checked)").parent('label').hide();
}
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Lzw1xg2n/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change the function `OnlySelecteds()` to this:

```
function OnlySelecteds() {
  $("input").closest('label').show();
  $("input:not(:checked)").closest('label').hide();
}
```

```js
function All() {
  $("input").parent().show();
}

function OnlySelecteds() {
  $("input").closest('label').show();
  $("input:not(:checked)").closest('label').hide();
}


//array of options
var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = "January";
choices[1] = "February";
choices[2] = "March";
choices[3] = "April";
choices[4] = "May";
choices[5] = "June";
choices[6] = "July";
choices[7] = "August";
choices[8] = "September";
choices[9] = "October";
choices[10] = "November";
choices[11] = "December";

var target = new Array()
target[0] = "9";
target[1] = "8";
target[2] = "11";

var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in choices) {
  //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
  j = i.toString();

  val = j;
  //cap will be the value/text of choices[i]
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  cap = choices[i];
  var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cbh.appendChild(cb);
  cb.name = cap;
  cb.value = val;
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click', updateText)
  if (target.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
    cb.checked = true;
  }

}
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});

updateText();

function updateText() {
  t.value = [null, ...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s, el) => el && el.checked ? s = (s || '') + el.value + '$#' : s || '')
}
function updateCheckboxes(x) {
  if ($('#SearchBar').val() == '') {
    $('#checkboxes > label').show();
  } else {
    $('#checkboxes > label').hide();
    $('#checkboxes > label:contains(' + $('#SearchBar').val() + ')').show();
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#data {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.multiselect {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1px;
  border: none;
  width: 100vw;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 75px;
}

.checkboxes {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="All()">All</span> | <span onclick="OnlySelecteds()">Selected</span> | <input id="SearchBar" placeholder="Search for options.." type="text" oninput="updateCheckboxes(this)" autocomplete="off">
<form>
  <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div id="c_b">
        <div id="checkboxes">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<textarea id="t" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```